# How can I add a meta site to the communities tab?

Tags: discussion, communities-list

I notice many screenshots showing their communities tab, and most of them have meta sites while mine doesn't. **How can I add meta sites to my communities tab?**

My communities tab:

[image: My Community tab image]

Example of another communities tab with a meta site:

[image]

> *Source: [Reputation shown for meta sites in site list drop-down is incorrect [duplicate]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/317851/reputation-shown-for-meta-sites-in-site-list-dropdown-is-incorrect)*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right of "Your Communities" is "edit". Clicking that brings up a text box where you can search for the sites (meta or otherwise) that you want to add to the list:

[image]